# window.onblur event in react js not getting invoked in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview

Code given below works perfectly in PC, Laptop, Tab, and Mobile Browsers. This code detects whether the user is opening another tab or other document or losing focus of the current browser window. But if we build a web app from this code using android web-view then this does not work at all.

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
useEffect(() =>
{
const onBlurCallback = () => onBlur();
window.addEventListener('blur', onBlurCallback);
return () =>
{
window.removeEventListener('blur', onBlurCallback);
};
}, []);

return (
<div className="App">

</div>
);
}

function onBlur()
{
alert('hello');
}

export default App;
```

Please suggest a solution that will work in the android web-view also.

Comment: You mean if you leave the android App, it isn't sending a blur event to the WebView? That's different from using a web browser but you can easily detect the user trying to leave the app and proceed accordingly. Is this about logging the user out? Please provide more information about the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `addEventListner` for the blur like that in React. You can try it like this:

```
<input type="text" onBlur={()=> //... your function here} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend Link : [Official Document](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#onblur)

You can use the `onBlur` function by adding it as an attribute of the `<input />`.

```js
function Example() {
  return (
    <input
      onBlur={(e) => {
        console.log('Triggered because this input lost focus');
      }}
      placeholder="onBlur is triggered when you click this input and then you click outside of it."
    />
  )
}
```